# How to reference a QlikSense sheet title in an expression

Tags: qliksense

I'm currently using the 'Title expression' to add some dynamic abilities to my sheet titles.  However, I would like to reference the actual sheet title in my expression.  i.e. the Title that is displayed in the Hub and on the Analysis Edit page, right above the 'Title expression'.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?  The problem is that if the title changes in the Hub 'My Sheet's' view, it isn't reflected in the Title expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the app title in expression with

```
DocumentTitle()
```

But its not possible yet to get the sheet name in a expression.